nodejs write to same file with multiple worker threads concurrently
I'm wondering whether we can write to the same file in multiple worker threads concurrently .
I've goolged around, and many people say that this operation may cause file write collisions, so I write the following nodejs code, trying to mimic this operation.
'use strict';

const {
  Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData,
} = require('node:worker_threads');
const fs =  require('node:fs');

const outputFile = './data.txt';
// const fd = fs.openSync(outputFile, 'a');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputFile, {
  flags: 'a',
});

if (isMainThread) {
  for( let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const workerName = `worker_${i}`;
    const worker = new Worker(__filename, { workerData: workerName });
    writeStream.write(`[worker_created]${workerName}\r\n`);
  }
} else {
  const workerName = workerData;
  writeStream.write(`[worker_started]${workerName}\r\n`);
  const start = Date.now();
  while (start + 5000 > Date.now()) {
    writeStream.write(`[worker_write]${workerName} ${Date.now()}\r\n`);
  }
  writeStream.write(`[worker_finished]${workerName}\r\n`);
}


The code is simple and self-explainable.
I think the content of data.txt will be messed when two threads write at the same time. But it turns out that the output file is NOT messed at all.
Can anybody explains this result, or do I make something wrong?
Any ideas are appreciated, thx in advance.

Writes to the underlying fileystem are abstracted by various things. This ensure that no parallel writes are possible, even if multiple processes try to write to the same destination. E.g. a scheduler decides which process has how many writes, till the next process is picked from the queue to write. (In simple terms.)

@Marc thx for your reply. According to many articles on the website, many developers say the writing to the same file in multiple processed may cause conflicts. But I can't reproduce the conflicts with my test code. Maybe it is handled properly by the underling OS

Maybe i am wrong, but perhaps only node does this. Perhaps write streams are blocking in some kind of situations and in C/C++ would you get a corrupt file. But when i think about logfiles in apache/nginx, there are also multiple threads that handle connections and write all to the same log file.
